# Json to Json transforms using json surfer or Jolt with varying attribute name

Tags: json

I had a problem where I had json that looked like this--where the "key" in the json is variable:

```
{
    "rpt":{
        "tests": [
            {"kerryA":[1,2,3,4]},
            {"wallB":[1,2]},
            {"MaryA":[1,2,3]}
        ]
    }
}
```

I wanted it to look like this:

```
 {
    "rpt": {
        "tests": [
            {
                "id":"kerryA",
                "testTaken":[1,2,3,4]
            },
            {
                "id":"wallB",
                "testTaken":[1,2]
            },
            {
                "name":"MaryA",
                "testTaken":[1,2,3]
            }
          ]
      }
  }
```

I looked at `JsonSurfer` and Jolt but they didn't seem to support the transform I was looking for.  I solved it by rewriting the `ObjectNode` by recursing through the json with Jackson.   While this wasn't bad, I feel like the json to json tranasformation that I looked at did not support the variable "key" well...  Other than rewriting and recursing like I did, is there a more elegant transformation solution?

Comment: Judging by the libraries you're referencing, I'm assuming you're looking for a Java solution?

Comment: From the command line, this is pretty easy using jq: `jq '.rpt.tests[] |= (to_entries[] | {id:.key, testTaken:.value})' input.json`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using **JOLT** with **shift** operation:

The spec would be:

```
[{
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
        "rpt": {
            "tests" : {
                "*": {
                    "*": {
                        "$": "rpt.tests[&2].id",
                        "@": "rpt.tests[&2].testTaken"                            
                    }                    
                }         
            }    
        }
    }
}
]
```

Take into account that Shiftr treats JSON arrays in the input data as Maps with numeric keys. That is why the double "*" and why rpt.tests[&2].id refers to the element of the array.

You can get more information about the shift operation at: https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/blob/master/jolt-core/src/main/java/com/bazaarvoice/jolt/Shiftr.java

An example to process it in Java would be:

```
Object inputJSON = JsonUtils.classpathToObject("/input.json");
List<Object> chainrSpecJSON = JsonUtils.classpathToList("/spec.json");

Chainr chainr = Chainr.fromSpec(chainrSpecJSON);
Object transformedOutput = chainr.transform(inputJSON);

System.out.println(JsonUtils.toPrettyJsonString(transformedOutput));
```

Where *input.json* is a file in the classpath with your entry data and *spec.json* is a file with the before code.